# Loading a static file in Angular during build

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm want to load the contents of a file and inject it as a string in TypeScript at build time. I understand that this code would ordinarily be server code, but what I want is to have a build step that reads the file and injects its contents as a string.

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  template: `<pre>${readFileSync('./example.code')}</pre>`
})
export class ExampleComponent { }
```

Assuming `example.code` just has `"Hello World"` I would want this file to be built as:

```
template: `<pre>"Hello World"</pre>`
```

I have found [babel-plugin-static-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-static-fs)  which I think should allow me to do this, but I was originally using `ng` (angular-cli) to build the project. I have done `ng eject` and updated webpack:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    /* snip */
    {
      "test": /\.ts$/,
      "use": [
        {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            plugins: ['babel-plugin-static-fs']
          }
        },
        {
          "loader": "@ngtools/webpack"
        }, ] } ] }
```

However, when I run `webpack`, I still get

> `Cannot find module 'fs'`

If I reverse the order of the loaders, it seems like babael does not like the `@` used in may annotations such as the `@Component` above so that loader does not work.

Is there any way to load a file as static content during an Angular project build?

Comment: WebPack will bundle anything that is imported. Have you tried `import str from './example.code'`? You might have to assign a raw-loader to the *.code rule.

Comment: @ThinkingMedia this is just an example; the files may themselves be TypeScript files. I want the source code from these files, and some of these files may also be used as project source code so I can't skip transpiling them.

Comment: You can configure your loader appropriately based on the file extension or even the location of the files themselves. It is relatively easy.

Comment: I want to transpile and string inject the same files; configuring the loaders is not the issue

Comment: Have you installed the package by running this command: `npm install babel-plugin-static-fs --save-dev`

Comment: You mean you want ts -> js -> string

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm not sure exactly what you mean. I want to replace `fs.readFileSync` with the contents of the file it's reading. I understand this can't be done at runtime in the browser, so I'm trying to do it at build time

Comment: @Vishal yes, the module is installed

Comment: You can't `ts -> js -> string` as that's already being done, but you could rename your ts files to something like `_ts -> _js -> string` that's not hard. You can then use the WebPack::DefinePlugin to do a search/replace of `fs.readFileSync` with a string value. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

Comment: @ThinkingMedia actually I can get this working as long as I create a fake `node_modules/fs`. It will find the import and transpile everything as expected _and_ that babel plugin will work properly. Seems like the main issue is trying to get webpack/TypeScript to find or ignore the `fs` module. I am including `@types/node` and `typeRoots: "node_modules/@types"` so I'm not really sure what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is actually related to the `tsconfig.app.json` file that Angular creates and uses for AoT. This is separate from the `tsconfig.json` used to actually build the project which *does* load `@types/node` as expected.

If you've created a project with `ng new`, you can change `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
- "types": [],
+ "types": ["node"],
```

This will have the AoT compiler use the type definitions from `@types/node`.